# Spark Df Check Column value based on the previous column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I am stuck at implementing a custom condition over spark DF. Basically I want to mark the column as 0 or 1 based on the Null value present in the column i.e if any

> column contains null the status corresponding to that row will be 0
>   else 1

```
 val someData = Seq(
    Row(8, "bat"),
    Row(64, "mouse"),
    Row(null, "rat")
  )

  val someSchema = List(
    StructField("number", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("word", StringType, true)
  )

  val someDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(
    sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
    StructType(someSchema)
  )
val fieldList: Seq[Column] = Seq(col("word"),col("number"))


 val df = fieldList.foldLeft(inputDf)(
      (inputDf, f) => {
       dfin = inputDf.withColumn(Status, lit(0))
        dfin
          .withColumn(
            Status,
            when(f.isNotNull and col("status").isin(0), 0).otherwise(1)
          )

      }
```

but it checks based on the last column in the `fieldList` but it should be like

```
col 1  col2  status
zyx .  pqe .  0
null . zyz . 1
xdc . null  1
null  null  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val df = someDF.withColumn("status", when(fieldList.map(x => col(x).isNull).reduce(_ || _), 1).otherwise(0)
```

The idea is first to turn each column name to a column and check if it null (the map) now a simple reduce would lead to true if at least one is null